# In airflow, have others noticed a longer delay between tasks in a subdag vs tasks in the main dag

Tags: delay, scheduler, airflow

I'm running airflow 1.9.0.  I put together a dag with all tasks simply having a 1 second sleep.  I have 20 of the tasks running in the main dag, 20 more running in a subdag and then 20 running in a sub-subdag.

There is a 2-3 second delay between the end of a task in the main dag and the beginning of the next task.  For tasks in the sub-dag, or even in the sub-subdag there is a 7-8 second delay between the end of one task and the beginning of the next.

I have observed the additional delays with both the CeleryExecutor and the LocalExecutor.

I have seen comments that airflow sees these delays as reasonable but I'm really curious as to why there is a difference in the sub-dag.

Comment: It might be more sufficient to ask this question the airflow developers, e.g. https://gitter.im/apache/incubator-airflow